# Algorithms and data-structures for working with time in a flow network

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, network-flow

I'm working on a system where I have a resource flow network, which should consider time.

#### For an example:

Think of a standard flow network, where each node is a warehouse, used for distributing an item, which has an expiration date. Additionally transporting an item from one node to another also takes time, so when an item is sent from the source, the time before it reaches the sink should be minimized.

The network contains sources(suppliers) and sinks(customers), and additionally nodes(warehouses) might have stock if an item already.

The demand for this item is distributed through out the network at different points in time, and a proper flow should be calculated.

However, you might get a change in demand in the middle of your timeline for an existing flow network, forcing you to change the flow in the network. When doing so, i would like to avoid having to re-calculate everything from the beginning, but instead just make subtle changes to the network so that it can take the new demand into account.

I've looked at standard flow algorithms, and have a hard time finding anything that considers time in the same way. I'm looking for something that might be able to push me in the right direction.

Does anyone know of any algorithms that address this kind of problem, or something similar? Or have any suggestions for a good data-structure for handling the time aspect?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of algorithms for this kind of problems:

**Dijkstra** - in your case: edge cost = time to send information from a node to another (if you don't know this kind of info you can use Dijkstra to calculate the shortest path and consider the shortest path is the fastest to). Complexity:  O(|V|lg|V| + |E|) - where V=vertices and E=edges

**A*** - if you are sure you have many unpredictable changes you can find a good heuristic function for your problem. I find A* pretty difficult to implement but it has a good complexity.

*Bellman-Ford, Johnson* - this may help too

Maybe you can find something useful here :
https://www.sics.se/~seif/DistributedAlgorithms/routing.pdf

or

http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~skutella/WAOA09-lncs.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already have implementations of Djikstra and A* for the graph searching part of the problem. The problem is considering time in the network flow. The routing link you posted is on to something, but it's not quite what i need. I'll try to formulate my question better.

Comment: You can try the classic algorithms used in communication protocols: link-state, distance vector... [http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~stan/classes/cs490/slides/networks4-ch4-4.pdf]